# sql server cumulative diff

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

i have 2 table namely `hrPft` having columns `cEmp` and `dpft`. and Table `hradv` with columns `iAdv`,`cEmp`,`dAmnt`. The data of the table look like as follows

Table hrPft

```
cEmp           dpft
1001        300.000
1002        1000.000
```

Table hradv

```
iAdv cEmp           dAmnt
1     1001          100.000
2     1001          50.000
3     1001          200.000
4     1001          10.000
1     1002          200.000
2     1002          500.000
3     1002          100.000
4     1002          100.000
```

My task is to display data as follows

```
cEmp    dpft                                        dAmnt
1001    300                                          100
1001    200(dpft-aAmnt)                               50
1001     150                                          200
1001      0(should display 0 when goes -ve)           50
1001      0                                         60(50+10)
```

Comment: I can't quite work out the logic behind the last two rows. Could you provide a bit more explanation please?

Comment: What version of sql-server?

Comment: when the difference between dfpt and dAmnt goes -ve substarction stops and should dispaly zero and dAmnt should add if they have any remaining rows

Comment: Don't add picture if you can't get the formatting right - pictures don't really help since we can't copy & paste them into our editors and work with them. Instead, if you want to show tabular data, highlight the block and hit the `{}` button - as I've done in my edit.

Comment: For the first three rows, they exactly correspond to one row from `hradv`. But then we seem to magically get two more rows, the first of which seems to not be related to any row from `hradv` though. Is that correct? (Or, at least, it's related to the third row above it, so the third row has produced two rows in the output?)

Comment: In the resultant table first row should represent the value from dpft of hrPft and dAmnt of hradv. But when coming to second row onward the column dpft should display like dpft-dAmnt and column dAmnt should display next value from hradv. This value of dAmnt will be subtracted from dpft of current row and will show in the next row.  when the difference between dfpt  goes -ve subtraction stops and should dispaly zero and dAmnt should add if they have any remaining rows

Comment: Last rows are the worst when dpft - dAmnt goes negative stop subtraction and display the column as 0.The column  dAmnt will display the reminder of the substraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces something close to your desired result set. You may have to play around with some of the comparisons (swapping `<`s and `<=`s, etc) to get the correct behaviour (that you've not specified) for when a subtraction reduces `dpft` to exactly 0.

I'll also not comment for the time being on how efficient this code may or may not be.

```
declare @hrpft table (cEmp int not null,dpft decimal(19,3) not null)
insert into @hrpft(cEmp,dpft) values
(1001,300.000 ),
(1002,1000.000)

declare @hradv table (iAdv int not null, cEmp int not null,dAmnt decimal(19,3) not null)
insert into @hradv(iAdv,cEmp,dAmnt) values
(1,1001,100.000 ),
(2,1001,50.000  ),
(3,1001,200.000 ),
(4,1001,10.000  ),
(1,1002,200.000 ),
(2,1002,500.000 ),
(3,1002,100.000 ),
(4,1002,100.000 )

select
    p.cEmp,
    p.dpft - COALESCE((select SUM(dAmnt) from @hradv a2 where a2.cEmp = p.cEmp and a2.iAdv < a.iAdv),0),
    a.dAmnt,
    a.iAdv
from
    @hrpft p
        inner join
    @hradv a
        on
            p.cEmp = a.cEmp
where p.dpft - COALESCE((select SUM(dAmnt) from @hradv a2 where a2.cEmp = p.cEmp and a2.iAdv < a.iAdv),0) >= 0
union all
select
    p.cEmp,
    0,
    COALESCE((select SUM(dAmnt) from @hradv a2 where a2.cEmp = p.cEmp and a2.iAdv <= a.iAdv),0) - p.dpft,
    a.iAdv
from
    @hrpft p
        inner join
    @hradv a
        on
            p.cEmp = a.cEmp
where p.dpft - COALESCE((select SUM(dAmnt) from @hradv a2 where a2.cEmp = p.cEmp and a2.iAdv <= a.iAdv),0) < 0
order by
    cEmp,iAdv
```

(Note, also, how I've presented your sample data - by writing it as table variables and `INSERT` statements, anyone can immediately copy and paste this into SSMS and start working with the data - you may want to consider using a similar way of presenting your sample data for any future questions).

Results:

```
cEmp                      dAmnt       iAdv
----------- ------------- ----------- -----------
1001        300.000       100.000     1
1001        200.000       50.000      2
1001        150.000       200.000     3
1001        0.000         50.000      3
1001        0.000         60.000      4
1002        1000.000      200.000     1
1002        800.000       500.000     2
1002        300.000       100.000     3
1002        200.000       100.000     4
```